# Как правильно предать параметр из параметризованной коллекции

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем здравствуйте, есть у меня обработчик кнопки в WinForms, при нажатии кнопки я получаю и вывожу в `CheckedListBox` содержимое коллекции. Сама коллекция состоит из двух текстовых полей, это имя рубрики и ее урл. Далее на форме я выбираю нужные мне позиции. И при нажатии второй кнопки я хочу сформировать параметризованный `List` из выделенных элементов. Но список я формирую только с теми `Items`, которые были выбраны,но  это только названия,а вот как мне получить еще и урлы выделенных позиций, не знаю, вот код.

Вот обработчик первой кнопки, которая получает список разделов.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string urlsRubr = "https://www.rabota66.ru/resume";   
    // тут получаю саму коллекцию все ок.
    var listt= pars.GetRubrik(urlsRubr).ToArray();

    // заполняю сам список на форме. Вывожу собственно имена рубрик. 
    // У x есть еще один параметр это x.UrlRubrik тут храниться сами урлы.    
    checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(listt.Select(x => x.NameRubrik).ToArray()); 
}
```

Вот обработчик второй кнопки, при нажатии на которою выбранные позиции запоминаются в такой же  параметризованный `List`. Но проблема в том, что я добавлю только имена рубрик, а как мне зацепить еще и сами урлы.
Может мне как то вывести на форме имя и невидимо урл, чтобы вместе потом загнать это все в коллекцию с выбранными пунктами?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
     List<Rubriks> Chek=new List<Rubriks>();
     foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
     {
         Chek.Add((Rubriks) item);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать возможности привязки данных.

Допустим, имеется:

Класс рубрики:

```
public class Rubric
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Искомый контрол:

```
CheckedListBox checkedListBox;
```

Заполненная коллекция:

```
var rubrics = new List<Rubric> {
    new Rubric { Name = "NameA", Url = "UrlA" },
    new Rubric { Name = "NameB", Url = "UrlB" }
};
```

У самого `CheckedListBox` некоторые свойства скрыты, поэтому приводим его к `ListBox`:

```
var listBox = (ListBox)checkedListBox;
listBox.DataSource = rubrics; // привязка данных
listBox.DisplayMember = nameof(Rubric.Name); // какое свойство будет выводиться
```

Далее в баттон-клике получаем выбранные элементы:

```
var checkedRubrics = checkedListBox.CheckedItems.OfType<Rubric>();
```

Можно добавить `ToList()`.

---

[nameof](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) - возвращает имя переменной, типа, члена. Без его использования можно было бы написать так:

```
listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Но если будет допущена опечатка, то известно об этом станет только в рантайме.

[OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) - возвращает из коллекции элементы указанного типа. Коллекция `CheckedItems` содержит элементы типа `object`. Вот мы их и приводим к нужному нам типу.

Comment: круто, а я всё искал `DisplayMember` в `CheckedListBox` и не нашел

Comment: Круто, очень круто. я не знал, что можно приводить почти одинаковые контроллы друг к друг, а поясните значение nameof и OfType

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch - дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если в классе переопределить ToString, томожно этот класс целиком отправлять в список чекбоксов. Например

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name {get;private set;}
    public int Id {get;private set;}

    public MyItem(string name, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

пример формы

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        var cb = new CheckedListBox();

        cb.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
            .Select(x => new MyItem($"My name is {x}", x)).ToArray());

        var bt = new Button() {Text = "press me"};

        bt.Click += (sender, args) => {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in cb.CheckedItems.OfType<MyItem>())
                sb.AppendLine($"checked:  id:{item.Id} with name:{item.Name}");
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        };

        this.Controls.Add(bt);
        this.Controls.Add(cb);

        bt.Left = 120;
    }
}
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]